# How to surround selected text inside textarea with <em> on key combination CTRL+i?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I select a text inside textarea and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> I would like to prepend and append HTML to it.
So if I select `dolor sit` inside `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet` I would like that text to become `Lorem ipsum <em>dolor sit</em> amet`. 
The same functionality like we can do it in WordPress.

https://codepen.io/ivan-topi/pen/dybXzvd

```js
jQuery('textarea').on('keydown', function(e) {
    // If key press combination is CTRL+i
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.key == 'i') {
        // Get selected text
        var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
        // Format new text
        selectedText = '<em>' + selectedText + '</em>';
        // Make changes
        // window.setSelection() if only it exists, but I couldn't find alternative?
    }
});
```

```html
<textarea>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `substring` to do above .i.e :

```js
jQuery('textarea').on('keydown', function(e) {

  // If key press combination is CTRL+i
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.key == 'i') {

    //getting length of text
    var length = $('#abc').val().length;
    //starting text
    var start_point = $('#abc')[0].selectionStart;
    //ending text
    var end_point = $('#abc')[0].selectionEnd;

    //getting selected text
    var selectedText = $('#abc').val().substring(start_point, end_point);
    console.log(selectedText);
    var replacement = "<em>" + selectedText + "</em>";
    $('#abc').val($('#abc').val().substring(0, start_point) + replacement + $('#abc').val().substring(end_point, length));

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="abc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
jQuery('div').on('keypress', function(e) {
   if (e.ctrlKey && e.key == 'i') {
    document.execCommand('italic')
   }
  
});
```

```css
div {
  border:black 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable='true'>Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Instead of having a `<textarea>`, you need a `<div contenteditable='true'>`. It's because the textarea can only have text, and if you apply italics, it would result in `<em>Lorem ipsum</em>` instead of actually being *Lorem ipsum*.

To apply italics, you can simply do `document.execCommand('italics')` when you press Ctrl + I in a contenteditable div. It will automatically add italics to the selected text.

Comment: Thank you for you time, it needs to be textarea, I don't have control over HTML. Seeing "<em>" isn't a big deal but it doesn't seem to be working https://codepen.io/ivan-topi/pen/MWgeEWo

Comment: using document.execCommand on a textarea won't work. Textareas are only for text, and you can't put html in them. You could use the answer that @Swati gave if you don't mind seeing the <em>, although there would be no italics. So if you need to use a textarea, then there is no way you can do it. Although you could the text from the textarea and then display it somewhere else.